# Android screen scaling problems

Tags: android, android-screen

I have been making an app which has a TextView on the screen which should touch the borders of the screen on the left and right sides.

But since android has its weird unit "dp", which changed with larger or smaller devices, it is a huge problem making the above thing work perfectly on every device.

I have created ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi & xxhdpi values for the text size. Still the size is not consistent on all phones.

Moreover, the size is different on 720p screens of different phones. Some touch the border, on some it reflows to the next line which is disgusting coz its a large size text, and on some it is far from the edges.

Is there an unit where I can put the value as a percentage of the screen? Or atleast an unit which has a constant maximum value for the the width and height?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I hope I undertood well, do you want to put a textview that it has all widh of the screen?
In this case you should use  the property android:width and put as a Fill parent for example; you don't use wrap content asa property this property adjust the textview size to the content.
You can do it with chart of properties on the editor or with a sentence on xml file.

Comment: That makes the widget take the whole screen... Not the text inside... textSize and layout_width are different attributes...

Comment: Sorry I don't undertand well, your proble is with the tex size or with thw text view?

Comment: I want the whole width of the screen to write "Hello" or something on every device devoid of screen size n density...

Comment: Weell this is a posiblility to do it ok?

Comment: Well this is a posiblility to do it ok? the first its put the text view with the properties android:width fill parent an  android:heigh wrap content. later you can get the resosolution or the size of the screen and with a form calculate the size of the text. Later I try to explain well; you ned a form that it realated the density of screnn with the pixels and  you will chage the text size